# Does the Webhooks for Instagram provide information when comment on Ad?

Tags: api, notifications, instagram, webhooks, facebook-webhooks

The Webhooks for Instagram does currently not trigger when a user comments on an Ad post. However, it does work with normal posts.

I read the Webhooks for Instagram guidance on the [support page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/webhooks).

In addition, I am using Webhooks already for getting new comments for normal posts.

However, I am currently struggling to getting the Webhook to work when a user comments on an Ad. If I say struggling I mean, I simply don't get the notification.

Is this feature currently not supported?

The actual result is that I don't get notified by the Webhook when a user comments on an Ad post.

The expected result is that the Webhook also triggers when a user comments on an Ad.

Comment: I found the following posts (https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/2014222981954539/) in the Facebook Group which confirms that this is currently not possible.

Comment: It sounds like you have answered your own question.  If so, you should go ahead and post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following post (facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/2014222981954539) in the Facebook Group which confirms that this is currently not possible.

We can only hope that Facebook will implement this feature in the future.